# Different Versions or Different Apps?

Tags: android, version, title

I created an android app that needs a different version for each different country because some interfaces and some options will be specific to each country. Can I use the same basic name “ethnic” followed by the country's name like for instance ethnic-USA, ethnic-Brazil, ethnic-UK, etc -or- by using such names they should be considered different apps?

Comment: So your question is about naming apps and not related to programming?

Comment: It is both. If you program different apps to fit the particularities of each country ( even if the core algorithms are the same ) then you need to name them differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement productFlavors for different countries and base on productFlavors perform business logic.

Comment: My worries are that Google play store may find those different country-tailored versions as a kind of "spam" and take down my apps.